# How to add a space when a certain pattern is found?

Tags: xslt

I have a major problem finding a way to add a space between two child elements.

```
<aaa>
    I want to add <bbb>a</bbb><ccc>space</ccc> between two words.
</aaa>
```

I want to add a space between the "a" and "space" words if the ccc element follows the bbb element immediately. Currently I apply template at aaa element level, and then handle bbb and ccc element in separate templates.

I have no idea how to detect this `</bbb><ccc>` pattern in advance.

Note: I do not know what words will be inside the bbb and ccc elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "b[. = 'a'
   and
    following-sibling::node()
                    [1]
                    [self::i
                   and
                     . = 'boy'
                    ]
      ]
   ">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when performed on the provided XML document**:

```
<aaa>
    I am <b>a</b><i>boy</i>.
</aaa>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<aaa>
    I am <b>a</b> <i>boy</i>.
</aaa>
```

**Do note**:

1. The use of the *identity rule* to copy all nodes.
2. The overriding of the identity rule with a specific template to carry out the addition of the space character exactly between the specified `<b>` and `<i>` nodes.
3. The match (XPath expression) pattern used to match exactly the wanted `<b>` node after which the space is to be inserted.
4. The code reuse of the template rule, both being applied and called by name.

Comment: +1, nice. For a more general version for adding a space between any adjacent elements inside an `aaa` element, the match expression of the latter template could be written as `aaa/*[following-sibling::node()[1]/self::*]`